Forming a matrix (i.e., linear operator) based on implicit description of coefficients
I'm implementing an algebraic multigrid solver based on "A Multigrid Tutorial, 2ed", and in chapter 3, the formation of the prolongation operator (a matrix denoted $P = I_{2h}^{h}$) is described as in the attached text below. My confusion is how does one fill in the coefficients of the $P$ based on listed equations?

If I simply begin to write out the equations using the values of $j$ such that $j \in [0...\frac{n}{2}-1]$, I don't see how the matrix coefficients comes from this: e.g. for $n = 8$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
j &= 0 \\
v_{2(0)}^{h} &= 1 v_{0}^{2h} \\
v_{2(0 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{0}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{1}^{2h} \\\\
j &= 1 \\
v_{2(1)}^{h} &= 1 v_{1}^{2h} \\
v_{2(1 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{1}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{2}^{2h} \\\\
j &= 2 \\
v_{2(2)}^{h} &= 1 v_{2}^{2h} \\
v_{2(2 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{2}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{3}^{2h} \\\\
j &= 3 \\
v_{2(3)}^{h} &= 1 v_{3}^{2h} \\
v_{2(3 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{3}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{4}^{2h}
\end{aligned} 
$$
so I think I must be making some mistake with the notation. The goal here is to program (matlab/julia) the creation of the matrix based on the formulas, so tips for this would also be very helpful.

To reason through the creation of a matrix based on the equations, it's helpful to rewrite the subscript $2j$ to simply $i$ since we know that prolongation $P \equiv I_{2h}^{h} : \mathbb{R}^{n_c} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n_f}$ where $n_c = \frac{n}{2} - 1$ and $n_f = 2n_c + 1$, and ultimately we want to know what coefficients are relevant for the $i^{th}$ equation in a system of linear equations with $n_f$ equations,
$$
\begin{aligned}
v_{i}^{h} &= v_{2j}^{h} = v_{j}^{2h}, && (1) \\
v_{i+1}^{h} &= v_{2j+1}^{h} = \frac{1}{2}v_{j}^{h} + \frac{1}{2}v_{j+1}^{h}, && (2)
\end{aligned}
$$
for $\ 0 \leq j \leq n_c$.
One can recognize this rewriting of the subscripts by referring to my question and rewriting it accordingly,
\begin{aligned}
j &= 0 \\
v_{0} = v_{2(0)}^{h} &= 1 v_{0}^{2h} && \text{Invalid} \\
v_{1} = v_{2(0 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{0}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{1}^{2h} \\\\
j &= 1 \\
v_{2} = v_{2(1)}^{h} &= 1 v_{1}^{2h} \\
v_{3} = v_{2(1 + 1)}^{h} &= \frac{1}{2}v_{1}^{2h} + \frac{1}{2} v_{2}^{2h} \\\\ 
\vdots
\end{aligned}
Since we know that $v_0$ is not a valid equation, i.e. there is no value for $v_0^{2h}$, then we know that $\forall i \in [2...n_f]$, we can use the governing equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ to define the coefficients for the matrix in row $i$ at column $j$.
I provide sample code implementing my description above for the prolongation matrix $P$.
function prolongation(n_coarse)
    n_fine = 2*n_coarse + 1
    P = zeros(Float64, n_fine, n_coarse)
    P[1, 1] = 1/2 # handles v_1 since v_0 is invalid

    # equation (1)
    function veven!(fine_dof, j) 
        if j != 0 && j != n_coarse + 1 # bounds check
            P[fine_dof, j] = 1
        end
    end

    # equation (2)
    function vodd!(fine_dof, j)
        j != 0 && j != n_coarse+1 && (P[fine_dof, j] = 1/2)
        j+1 != n_coarse+1 && (P[fine_dof, j+1] = 1/2)
    end
   
    j = 1 # start at j = 1 since j = 0 is special case
    n_equations_per_j = 2 
    for fine_dof = 2:n_fine
        # j increments once per two equations (i.e., fine_dofs)
        j = fine_dof ÷ n_equations_per_j

        # apply functions based on parity
        if iseven(fine_dof)
            veven!(fine_dof, j)
        else
            vodd!(fine_dof, j)
        end
    end  
    return P      
end

Note that there are more efficient ways to create this matrix since it would be a sparse matrix, but this sample code is just supposed to mimic the mathematical logic as closely as possible. See this answer for another way to make the matrix. See this function for an implementation using C++ and Eigen.
